# AWS Application ELB swallowing the 5XXs errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Since one week we are using "application" ELB for our applications. In ELB monitoring we couldn't see any 5XXs responses, even though there were many 5XXs in our application accesslogs.

Maybe it could be a configuration error!?

Comment: Turn on logging for the ELB.  Review the logs.  See what you find.  Are these requests getting logged by the ELB?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 5xx in the application logs but not in ELB metrics. If there is 5xx in application logs It's for that application which connects to. 
It's not for the load balancer. So ELB is not receiving 504.

Comment: It was "Sum HTTP 5XXs Count" in ELB monitoring. It should be the number of reponses with http statuscode 5XXs and greater than 0, because the application has send some 500 Responds back to ELB definitively.